# How to update all fragments from Activity/async/service

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making application in which I will have three fragments. And they all will be updated with the same data. Data will be changing live. So what is the best approach to feed all fragments with the same data?
I was thinking about creating service or asynctask, but then I will be able to update only one fragment, right? I was thinking also maybe updating some global variable at Activity which is handling fragments, maybe this will be better approach?

Comment: Consider the `Observable/Observer` pattern. Or `RxJava2`

Comment: Or use the Android Architecture Components ViewModel. You can use the same ViewModel in all three fragments using the parents activity Lifecycle. Load the data in the ViewModel and observe LiveData in fragments. This would give you a lot of benefits, like data persisting during configuration changes.